# Const not being const?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

My question is why does the value of variable a changes, although I've declared it as const? Sorry if this is a trivial question.

```
const int a = 8;
int* ptr = &a;

printf("variable: %d \n", a);
printf("pointer: %d \n", *ptr);

*ptr = 1;
printf("pointer: %d \n", *ptr);
printf("variable: %d \n", a);
```

Output: 8 8 1 1

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: So you ask why the code riots if **you** break a contract **you** guaranteed?  But your compiler should have warned, any reason you ignored that? Note: C does not have symbolic constants other than _enum-constants_.

Comment: Generally speaking, the C-language standard does permit casting from 'pointer to const' to 'pointer to non-const', so the exact behavior of the program during runtime is undefined. More specifically, the runtime behavior of this program is compiler-dependent. If the compiler allocates const variables at a read-only segment of the executable image, then you will get a memory-access violation (aka *segmentation fault*) when the line `*ptr = 1` is executed. If it allocates them at a read-write segment of the executable image, then this line will be executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have qualified `a` as `const`, but when you assign its address to a pointer, this discards the effect of `const` and `a` can be now manipulated easily using `ptr`. This most likely invokes an undefined behaviour.

GCC will show a warning when you compile your program:

```
warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
        int* const ptr = &a;
```

If you want to not experience this effect, declare the pointer variable as a pointer to a constant.
Example: `const int* ptr=&a;`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Surprising! Your answer is correct. You should have say that this behavior is undefined...

Comment: Yes I edited after posting it initially.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: The answer is **not** correct!

Comment: Can you explain why @Olaf?

Comment: @skrtbhtngr: How about reading the standard or - at least - the answers to the dup?

Comment: That I've read; I am asking is there some specific part that is incorrect in context to what the OP asked?